# Python with alternative keywords

Tags: python, python-2.x, language-design

A while ago, a user on [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) had an idea:

> [How about a language where all of the core commands are PPCG usernames?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30148665#30148665) -- [Helka Homba](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/121917/helka-homba)

A list was made of username/(keyword|builtin function) pairs, but nobody really wanted to actually make the code, so it kinda went on hold.

Recently (read: yesterday) [another user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/157689/muddyfish) suggested using the `tokenize` module, so I did. With his help, [I finished some py2 code for replacing the names](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/ThePeoplesPython/blob/master/main.py).

Here is my code:

```
import tokenize
import ast
import sys



def handle_token(type, token, (srow, scol), (erow, ecol), line):
    # Return the info about the tokens, if it's a NAME token then replace it

    if tokenize.tok_name[type] == "NAME":
        token = token_names.get(token, token)
    return (type, token, (srow, scol), (erow, ecol), line)


def run(assignments="assignments.txt",open_from="peoples.txt"):
    with open(assignments, "r") as f:
        # Read the replacements into token_names
        global token_names
        token_names = ast.literal_eval(f.read())

    with open(open_from) as source:
        # Get the tokenized version of the input, replace it, and untokenize into pretty output
        tokens = tokenize.generate_tokens(source.readline)
        handled_tokens = (handle_token(*token) for token in tokens)

        output = tokenize.untokenize(handled_tokens)

    with open(open_from[:-4]+"-output.txt",'w') as outfile:
        # Write to the output file
        outfile.write(output)

    return output


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        if len(sys.argv) > 2:
            try:exec run(assignments=sys.argv[1],open_from=sys.argv[2])
            except:pass
        else:
            try:exec run(assignments=sys.argv[1])
            except:pass
    else:
        try:exec run()
        except:pass
```

This is the content of `main.py`.  It uses [`assignments.txt`](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/ThePeoplesPython/blob/master/assignments.txt), which is a file containing a python dict of the replacement pairs.

```
{"Martin":"False",
"Geobits":"None",
"Dennis":"True",
"adnan":"and",
"rainbolt":"as",
"buttner":"assert",
"flawr":"break",
"aditsu":"class",
"katenkyo":"continue",
"quill":"def",
"nathan":"del",
"hobbies":"elif",
"helkahomba":"else",
"irk":"except",
"ender":"finally",
"peter":"for",
"conor":"from",
"gnibbler":"global",
"calvins":"if",
"obrien":"import",
"taylor":"in",
"fryamtheeggman":"is",
"starman":"lambda",
"sp3000":"nonlocal",
"phinotpi":"not",
"xnor":"or",
"maltysen":"pass",
"mego":"raise",
"alex":"return",
"easterly":"try",
"molarmanful":"while",
"minxomat":"with",
"optimizer":"yield",
"mbomb007":"abs",
"digital":"all",
"trauma":"any",
"asciionly":"ascii",
"zyabin":"bin",
"bkul":"bool",
"chris":"chr",
"jesteryoung":"classmethod",
"elendia":"enumerate",
"gcampbell":"eval",
"fatalize":"filter",
"sandbox":"help",
"zgarb":"id",
"phase":"input",
"loovjo":"int",
"minibits":"issubclass",
"lynn":"len",
"doorknob":"map",
"upgoat":"max",
"briantompsett":"memoryview",
"downgoat":"min",
"jimmy23013":"open",
"destructiblewatermelon":"ord",
"ninjabearmonkey":"pow",
"you":"print",
"djmcmayhem":"range",
"qwerpderp":"round",
"orlp":"sorted",
"timmyd":"staticmethod",
"muddyfish":"sum",
"balint":"super",
"trichoplax":"tuple",
"quartata":"zip"}
```

An example `peoples.txt`:

```
peter i taylor djmcmayhem(10):
    you(list(set(i)))
```

Should output:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(list(set(i)))
```

What does the code do? It takes in an input file (by default `peoples.txt` in the same dir as `main.py`) and translates it from "People's Python" to standard python, and executes the result.  It also writes the compiled "normal" code into `<input_file_name>-output.txt`, by default `peoples-output.txt`

Run as `python main.py custom/assignments.txt path/to/inputfile.txt` (`inputfile.txt` is the People's Python code and `assignments.txt` is the dict of assignments you're using)

In terms of style, how can I improve this?

The things I notice:

- Probably could some more comments.
- Replace `ast.literal_eval` with another method that doesn't involve using *any* eval. Not sure if this is even possible though. Would best practice say to just include the massive dictionary in `main.py`?
- Is using blank `except:`s with no special error (i.e. `except SyntaxError:`) okay in this situation?

Comment: I found typo. `djmcmayhem` should be spelt `drhamjam`

Comment: @Downgoat how do you figure that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Some Musings about Exceptions***

**(1) NEVER pass on every single exception!**

You're basically absorbing *every possible exception* without usefulness.  Normally, to prevent runtime crashes, I do this with my excepts when I want to catch all:

```
try:
    # some code here...
except Exception as e:
    print "An exception has occurred:\n%s" % str(e)
```

... which will put a nicer message.  Of course, you can expand this by defining different types to capture in the except blocks.  There may be cases for this, but since this isn't a code golf challenge, you can do this here instead.

**(2) "Blank" `except` blocks**

There's a rule of thumb that I abide by:  "In most cases, you should always try and catch the most narrow exception that you expect to end up seeing in a `try`/`except` block, with an ultimate "catch-all" block later to handle any unexpected exceptions."  That basically means that if I'm trying to catch an "Invalid JSON" error when running `json.load` (you'll see why I mention this later), I'd do something like this:

```
with open('jsondata.json', 'r') as f:
    try:
        data = json.load(f)
    except ValueError:
        print "Could not properly parse JSON data, is the file 'jsondata.json' comprised of actual JSON data?"
```

In effect, we do something different with a `ValueError` (we could pass, or we could simply quit, or we can print a nice message like this does), but for all other `Exception`s will not capture them and will raise whatever exception it was trying to raise.  Let's say, though, this was in a `run()` function, and I call the `run` function in a manner like you do in your code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        run()
    except Exception as e:
        print "An unhandled exception has occurred:\n%s" % str(e)
```

Since most errors inherit from Exception this captures all other errors, but not warnings, this will allow for us to capture unhandled exceptions and 'handle' them as a "final option" type of try/except block, for when they aren't handled in other blocks below `run` directly.

There are always rare cases where you want to do *nothing* when an exception happens, so you can use `pass` in those cases, but in 99% of all cases, you should ***not*** be simply 'allowing exceptions to pass on without raising some notice'.

---

**Replace `ast` with `json` instead**

JSON data is basically a structured `dict`.  Since you're storing a `dict` and it meets the most basic JSON formatting, we can just parse your `assignments` file as JSON instead, and remove the `literal_eval` and `import ast`.  This does require you to `import json` instead of `import ast` but this is a more sane approach:

```
with open(assignments, "r") as f:
    # Read the replacements into token_names
    global token_names
    token_names = json.load(f)
```

This way, we don't have to worry about `ast` and having a literal evaluation that could cause evil in the future.  This also permits us to error out proper with an exception if we don't have a valid assignments file.  (And we can handle it with customized error messages if we wish).

As for storing the 'massive dict' in main.py, if it's likely to expand in the future leave it in its own file, and continue to load it as a JSON object as my suggestion here has.

---

**This isn't code golf!  Whitespace is a good thing!**

Your code is hard to read when your try/except blocks and such are all golfed to remove whitespace.  Add whitespace for readability.

---

**You don't need that many try/accept blocks around your 'run' calls, and you don't need `exec` either!**

You have four separate try/except blocks, yet all they do is silently let exceptions go by.  Taking into account I don't suggest using 'pass' on exceptions that could be important, we can just simply take a page from my book, and change your code to have one try/except block wrapped around *all* the `run` calls, and handle exceptions whenever they come up, without having individual try/except blocks just for each call.

You also don't need the `exec` calls you have in here.

So, ultimately, you save some code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            if len(sys.argv) > 2:
                run(assignments=sys.argv[1], open_from=sys.argv[2])

            else:
                run(assignments=sys.argv[1])
        else:
                run()
    except Exception as e:
        print "An exception has occurred:\n%s" % str(e)
```

---

***Nitpicking Section***

I'mma nitpick a little here with some of your code, and bring more suggestions that are minor/aesthetic in nature, rather than code-critical.  These suggestions are reflected below though.

**`type` is actually a builtin, use a different name in `handle_token`**

This one's fairly obvious, but `type` is actually a built-in.  Shadowing built-ins is bad if you eventually could use a builtin, so let's replace `type` with `type_` in `handle_token`, to get rid of the "Shadows built-in 'type'" problems.

**Unnecessary parentheses on 'return' in `handle_token`**

You don't need the parentheses around the 'return' object.  It'll return all the objects you specify as a tuple anyways, and operate as we expect it to.

**She-bang line: `python2` and `python` are identical**

> NOTE: When this answer was written, the code had not yet been updated to reflect OP's removal of the shebang line.  The shebang line works, but it needs tweaked as per this part of the review; it's added back in for this code, accordingly, because it's part of the *original* code, but needed a tweak.  Refer to the revision history for the original question for more.

In most cases, the current guidelines that `python` is Python 2 and `python3` is Python 3 from Python upstream are still in play.  Consider any Linux system - `python3` is the Python 3 interpreter, but a call to `python` when both Python 2 and 3 are installed is a call to Python 2.7.  Because `python2` may not exist in the env either, it's sane to call `python` instead of `python2`.  Alternatively, remove the shebang line so you can't call the program as a script directly and *have* to invoke the file via a call to `python` with `python main.py [args]`.

**Use of a `global` but not defining it at the Module level**

This is more or less me griping about PyCharm (my IDE) being annoying.  It reports that your use of `global token_names` is not defined at the module level.  While ultimately this has no real effect on the execution of your program, you can easily avoid this notice by just putting `token_names = None` in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block right before the try/except block.  And I did this, just to suppress the IDE alert.  (It doesn't affect execution apparently, and still works as it should)

---

---

This is your code with all my suggestions from above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tokenize
import sys
import json


def handle_token(type_, token, (srow, scol), (erow, ecol), line):
    # Return the info about the tokens, if it's a NAME token then replace it

    if tokenize.tok_name[type_] == "NAME":
        token = token_names.get(token, token)
    return type_, token, (srow, scol), (erow, ecol), line


def run(assignments="assignments.txt", open_from="peoples.txt"):
    with open(assignments, "r") as f:
        # Read the replacements into token_names
        global token_names
        token_names = json.load(f)

    with open(open_from) as source:
        # Get the tokenized version of the input, replace it, and untokenize into pretty output
        tokens = tokenize.generate_tokens(source.readline)
        handled_tokens = (handle_token(*token) for token in tokens)

        output = tokenize.untokenize(handled_tokens)

    with open(open_from[:-4]+"-output.txt", 'w') as outfile:
        # Write to the output file
        outfile.write(output)

    return output


if __name__ == "__main__":
    token_names = None
    try:
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            if len(sys.argv) > 2:
                exec run(assignments=sys.argv[1], open_from=sys.argv[2])

            else:
                run(assignments=sys.argv[1])
        else:
                run()
    except Exception as e:
        print "An exception has occurred:\n%s" % str(e)
```

Comment: And my assignments.txt is already formatted a JSON object, correct? Thanks the advice!

Comment: @Riker Correct - a basic dict like the one you have is also a compatible JSON object - so we just load it as if it is a JSON object and all works as we expect it to.  No more `literal_eval` :)

Comment: I have reread your quesiton, you may actually *want* to use `exec` here, but I have a better approach to it.  If you repost for a supplementary CR I may be able to give some suggestions.